# Python / Selenium - using a conditional in an xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I need to find a particular element in some webpages which are basically identical in structure, using the following xpath:

`//*[@id="detailPCTtableHeader"]/tbody/tr[10]/td[2]/div/span/span[1]/text()`

The problem is that in some pages `tr[10]` is `tr[11]`.

Is there a way to tell Selenium to search for `tr[10]` *or* `tr[11]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `position()` to evaluate the index:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("id('detailPCTtableHeader')/tbody/tr[position()=10 or position()=11]/td[2]/div/span/span[1]")
```

Answer (score 2):

> *"Is there a way to tell Selenium to search for `tr[10]` or `tr[11]`?"*

Use `position()` :

```
tr[position() = 10 or position() = 11]
```

Alternatively, if only one of `tr[10]` and `tr[11]` ever exists at a time, meaning it is always the last `tr`, you can simply use `last()` :

```
tr[last()]
```